# Add layout constraints in UINavigationBar programmatically

Tags: ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have a UIViewController displaying a view with a UINavigationBar. This UINavigationBar is created automatically as it is in a UINavigationController.

I would like to display a second UINavigationBar on top of the first, for a specific mode, with a translation animation from the top.

I've figured out that as the UINavigationBar was created automatically, it was easier to add the second UINavigationBar IN the first one, with a simple :

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:secondNavigationBar];
```

I'm now trying to add a "y" constraint to be able to translate the secondNavigationBar :

```
self.secondNavigationBarTopConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:secondNavigationBar
                                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                         toItem:self.navigationController.navigationBar
                                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                                     multiplier:1.0
                                                                       constant:-secondNavigationBar.height];
```

Then,

```
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar addConstraint: self.secondNavigationBarTopConstraint];
```

tells me

> Cannot modify constraints for UINavigationBar managed by a
>   controller

and

```
[self.view addConstraint: self.secondNavigationBarTopConstraint];
```

tells me

> The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint

I'm not familiar with auto-layouts constraints... your help would be really appreciated :) Thanks !

Answer (score -4):

Instead of using constraints you could try manually setting the frame, like so:

`self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44, screenWidth, screenHeight)`

which would put the navBar 44 pixels from the top, allowing space to insert another bar

Comment: This won't work if the orientation changes, or the navbar size otherwise changes.

Comment: Definitely works, this is classic programmatic UI in iOS. You're given a callback when the orientation changes, where you will use the same code to resize the navbar accordingly @windup